# JavaScript: callback function parameter with same name as other variable?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var str = 'internet';

performAction(function(str) {
    console.log(str);
});
```

Is there a problem with having a private variable `str` and also having a callback function with a parameter of the same name?

Thanks!

Comment: No - just don't forget that it's not actually the same variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is just a standard scope situation - the fact that it is an anonymous function expression passed as a parameter to another function doesn't matter. Note that within your `performAction()` function (which you don't show) it will not have any access to the `str` that is the parameter of the callback function - if `performAction()` references `str` it will get the global "internet" variable (or its own local `str` if defined).

A function's parameters are, for scope purposes, the same as that function's local variables, which means they mask other variables of the same name from outer scope - but variables with different names can still be accessed even if defined in a wider scope.

Where it could get confusing is if you do something like this:

```
var str = "internet";

(function(str) {
  console.log(str); // "internet"
  str = "local param";
  console.log(str); // "local param"
})(str);

console.log(str); // "internet"
```

In that case I have a function with a parameter called `str` but when I call it I'm passing in a different `str`. Note that changing `str` within that function only changes the local `str`, not the global one. They are two different variables...

Answer (score 8):

There is **technically** no problem with it. The function will log the `str` that is currently in scope (your parameter).

For obvious reasons, this is not considered a good idea. At the very least, it makes for unreadable code.