# How to access external function variables from inner functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am just getting the ropes of JS Fundamentals, bear with me.

Following is the code :

```
function FuncWithMathOps(x){
var x=x;

console.log("Value of x : "+x);

var SUM = function(x){
    var x=x;

    console.log("Value of x : "+x);
    console.log("Value of this.x : "+this.x);
}

var MUL = function(x){
    var x=x;

    console.log("Value of x : "+x);
    console.log("Value of this.x : "+this.x);
}

return {
    SUM:SUM,
    MUL:MUL
};

}
```

Both external function and inner functions variable names are same i.e., `x` & `y`. How do i access external function `FuncWithMathOps` variables from inner functions `SUM` & `MUL` ?

Comment: This does maybe sound stupid, but: Just don't name variables identically when you have to access them across scopes?

Comment: This may also be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453580/javascript-callback-function-parameter-with-same-name-as-other-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: callback function parameter with same name as other variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453580/javascript-callback-function-parameter-with-same-name-as-other-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a variable *self* which persist the reference to `this`, which can be used later.

```js
function FuncWithMathOps(x) {
  this.x = x;
  var self = this;

  console.log("Value of x : " + x);
  var SUM = function(x) {
    console.log("Value of x : " + x);
    console.log("Value of this.x : " + self.x);
    return x + self.x;
  }

  return {
    SUM: SUM
  };
}

var fn = new FuncWithMathOps(10);
console.log(fn.SUM(5))
```

You can also use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```js
function FuncWithMathOps(x) {
  this.x = x;
  console.log("Value of x : " + x);
  var SUM = function(x) {
    console.log("Value of x : " + x);
    console.log("Value of this.x : " + this.x);
    return x + this.x;
  }

  return {
    SUM: SUM.bind(this)
  };
}

var fn = new FuncWithMathOps(10);
console.log(fn.SUM(5))
```